# Stopping the program while executing a function in a timer in Android programming

Tags: android, function

I have a function like the following and I want to call it with the code you see after a few seconds but the program stops as soon as that code is executed.
I also used try{}catch(){}, but still the program just stops and I do not notice the problem.
Please help me.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                                ind(y);
                  
                            }
                        }
                    }, 5000);


 public void ind(int[] arr) {
    for (int ix = 0; ix <=arr.length; ix++) {
        if (arr[ix] == 99) {
            index = ix;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the rest of the class that contains this code + anything else that is relevant

Comment: I only type this code in an activity where there is nothing, but it does not work at all

Comment: The other parts of the program work and do not work in the part I mentioned